# Why my glutDisplayFunc do not update in real time?

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, glut

I realized that when I  run this code the triangle appear rotating in real time

```
def main():

   glutInit(sys.argv)
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
   glutInitWindowSize(600,400)
   glutCreateWindow("Seismic")
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   glLoadIdentity()
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
   glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
   glPushMatrix()

   gluPerspective(45, (600/400), 0, 15) 
   glTranslatef(0,-0.2,-1.5)   
   k = 0
   while k<10000:

       glRotatef(0.1, 0, 1, 0) 

       k +=1
       print k

       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
       glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
       glColor3f(1,0,0,0)
       glVertex3f(0,0,0)
       glColor3f(0,1,0,0)
       glVertex3f(0,0.5,0)
       glColor3f(0,0,1,0)
       glVertex3f(0.5,0.5,0)
       glEnd() 
       glutSwapBuffers()

       #time.sleep(1)

   glutMainLoop()
   return
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

But in the other hand when I use glutDisplayFunc y have to wait to finish the loop in order to get the triangle.

```
def triangulo():
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
   glColor3f(1,0,0,0)
   glVertex3f(0,0,0)
   glColor3f(0,1,0,0)
   glVertex3f(0,0.5,0)
   glColor3f(0,0,1,0)
   glVertex3f(0.5,0.5,0)
   glEnd() 
   glutSwapBuffers()

def main():

   glutInit(sys.argv)
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
   glutInitWindowSize(600,400)
   glutCreateWindow("Seismic")
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   glLoadIdentity()
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
   glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
   glPushMatrix()

   gluPerspective(45, (600/400), 0, 15) #3D effect
   glTranslatef(0,-0.2,-1.5)  # Ocurre el pocicionamiento
   k = 0
   while k<10000:
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
     glRotatef(0.1, 0, 1, 0) #vector de rotacion  (degrees,(eje-vector))
     glutDisplayFunc(triangulo) 
     k +=1
     print k 
     #time.sleep(1)

   glutMainLoop()
   return

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I'd like to know how to get the rotating triangle in real time when glutDisplayFunc is used.

Answer (score 3):

`glutDisplayFunc` is not a fancy way to call a function. It simply tells GLUT that, when *it* wants to display the screen, it will call the function you pass. It's not going to call the given function immediately.

See, when you call `glutMainLoop`, that means that GLUT now owns your application. It will call whatever callbacks you have registered, but that is the only way to do get something done. If GLUT decides that the screen needs to be redisplayed, then the function you registered with `glutDisplayFunc` will be called.

What you want to do is two things:

1. Force GLUT to redisplay the screen at a reasonable frequency. Normally, GLUT will only update the screen's display if something uncovers part of the window, or if it gets moved around or so forth. That is, GLUT assumes that animation isn't happening.
2. Everytime the screen is updated, adjust the rotation angle for some object.

#1 requires having your display function call `glutPostRedisplay`. This tells GLUT to redisplay the screen. And #2 is something you've already done. Ultimately, what you really want is to take everything that's in the `while` loop and make it a function. One that ends in a call to `glutPostRedisplay`:

```
def triangulo():
    glRotatef(0.1, 0, 1, 0) 

    k +=1
    print k

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
    glColor3f(1,0,0,0)
    glVertex3f(0,0,0)
    glColor3f(0,1,0,0)
    glVertex3f(0,0.5,0)
    glColor3f(0,0,1,0)
    glVertex3f(0.5,0.5,0)
    glEnd() 
    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()

def main():
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(600,400)
    glutCreateWindow("Seismic")
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
    glPushMatrix()

    gluPerspective(45, (600/400), 0, 15) 
    glTranslatef(0,-0.2,-1.5)   
    k = 0
    glutDisplayFunc(triangulo) #Calling the triangulo function    
    glutMainLoop()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```